# Output the value/word after one pattern has been found in string in variable (grep, awk, sed, pearl etc)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a program that prints data into the console like so (separated by space):

```
variable1 value1
variable2 value2
variable3 value3
varialbe4 value4
```

**EDIT:** Actually the output can look like this:

```
data[variable1]: value1
pre[variable2] value2
variable3: value3
flag[variable4] value4
```

In the end I want to search for a part of the name e.g. for `variable2` or `variable3` but only get `value2` or `value3` as output.
**EDIT:** This single value should then be stored in a variable for further processing within the bash script.

I first tried to put all the console output into a file and process it from there with e.g.

```
# value3_var="$(grep "variable3" file.log | cut -d " " -f2)"
```

This works fine but is too slow. I need to process ~20 of these variables per run and this takes ~1-2 seconds on my system. Also I need to do this for ~500 runs. **EDIT:** I actually do not need to automatically process all of the ~20 'searches' automatically with one call of e.g. awk. If there is a way to do it automaticaly, it's fine, but ~20 calls in the bash script are fine here too.

Therefore I thought about putting the console output directly into a variable to remove the slow file access. But this will then eliminate the newline characters which then again makes it more complicated to process:

```
# console_output=$(./programm_call)
# echo $console_output
variable1 value1 variable2 value2 variable3 value3 varialbe4 value4
```

**EDIT:** IT actually looks like this:

```
# console_output=$(./programm_call)
# echo $console_output
data[variable1]: value1 pre[variable2] value2 variable3: value3 flag[variable4] value4
```

I found a solution for this kind of string arangement, but these seem only to work with a text file. At least I was not able to use the string stored in `$console_output` with these examples

[How to print the next word after a found pattern with grep,sed and awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606867/how-to-print-the-next-word-after-a-found-pattern-with-grep-sed-and-awk)

So, how can I output the next word after a found pattern, when providing a (long) string as variable?

PS: grep on my system does not know the parameter -P...

Comment: *I need to process ~20 of these variables per run and this takes ~1-2 seconds on my system.* Please also post the code th process more than 1 of these variables (2 vars is enough as an example). It may be possible to optimize that part, too.

Comment: If you are trying to search for one variable at a time then you you can't do this job noticably faster than you already are because that's require a shell loop to call grep (or anything else) one string at a time and THAT is what eats up the time - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Note that you have a functionality problem related to false matches too though - in your sample input you should include at least one "variable" string that is a subset of another variable strings (e.g. `variable3: val1` and `variable33: val2`), and at least one case where the variable you're searching for also shows up as a value elsewhere, e.g. (`variable4: variable3`). If your data can accept strings with regexp metachars (`foo.bar: val`) then you should cover those cases too.

Comment: To be 100% clear, when you say `~20 calls in the bash script are fine here too` - no, it would not be fine. You cannot get any kind of reasonable execution speed doing 20 calls to any tool - that's why your batch of greps are taking 2 seconds instead of 20 milliseconds, it's the act of calling grep that's taking all of the time, not the act of grep running.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use `awk`:

```
$ cat ip.txt
data[variable1]: value1
pre[variable2] value2
variable3: value3
flag[variable4] value4

$ cat var_list
variable1
variable3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}
       {for(k in a) if(index($1, k)) print $2}' var_list ip.txt 
value1
value3
```

To use output of another command as input file, use `./programm_call | awk '...' var_list -` where `-` will indicate `stdin` as input.

> This single value should then be stored in a variable for further processing within the bash script.

If you are doing further text processing, you could do it within `awk` and thus avoid a possible slower `bash` loop. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for details.

Speed up suggestions:

- Use `LC_ALL=C awk '..'` if input is ASCII (Note that as pointed out in comments, this doesn't apply for all cases, so you'll have to test it for your use case)
- Use `mawk` if available, that is usually faster. `GNU awk` may still be faster for some cases, so again, you'll have to test it for your use case
- Use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which is usually faster than other `grep` programs.

```sh
$ ./programm_call | rg -No -m1 'variable1\S*\s+(\S+)' -r '$1'
value1
$ ./programm_call | rg -No -m1 'variable3\S*\s+(\S+)' -r '$1'
value3
```

Here, `-o` option is used to get only the matched portion. `-r` is used to get only the required text by replacing the matched portion with the value from the capture group. `-m1` option is used to stop searching input once the first match is found. `-N` is used to disable line number prefix.

Comment: Do you have any reference for why setting `LC_ALL=C` would speed up hash lookups?

Comment: @EdMorton just tried some experiments, and hash lookups don't seem to benefit from setting LC_ALL=C..

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunatelly this also requires file access which I would like to prevent. Also I think my description was not exactly clear in this point, so I edited it a bit

Comment: @Orikson it would've helped if you could show what kind of further processig you need within a bash script.. it may be faster to do it within awk itself.. anyways, I've edited the answer, see if it helps.. I've also shown how you can pass command ouptut to awk instead of using file input

Comment: @Orikson also, when you are processing one variable at a time, it is better to save results of `./programm_call` in a file, otherwise `./programm_call` will consume time for every variable processing

Answer (score 1):

Exit after the first `grep` match, like so:

```
value3_var="$(grep -m1 "variable3" file.log | cut -d " " -f2)"
```

Or use Perl, also exiting after the first match. This eliminates the need for a pipe to another process:

```
value3_var="$(perl -le 'print $1, last if /^variable3\s+(.*)/' file.log)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly both do not result in any output at all in my tries. Also, this solution again uses file access, where I would need processing the data from a variable

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, how about feeding
the output of `programm_call` directly to the `awk` script instead of
assinging a shell variable.

```
./programm_call | awk '
# the following block is invoked line by line of the input
{
    a[$1] = $2
}
# the following block is executed after all lines are read
END {
    # please modify the print statement depending on your required output format
    print "variable1 = " a["variable1"]
    print "variable3 = " a["variable3"]
}'
```

Output:

```
variable1 = value1
variable3 = value3
```

As you see, the script can process all (~20) variables at once.

**[UPDATE]**

Assumptions including the provided information:

- The `./program_call` prints approx. 50 pairs of "variable value"
- `variable` and `value` are delimited by blank character(s)
- `variable` may be enclosed with `[` and `]`
- `variable` may be followed by `:`
- We have interest with up to 20 variables out of the ~50 pairs
- We use just one of the 20 variables at once
- We don't want to invoke `./program_call` whenever accessing just one variable
- We want to access the variable values from within bash script
- We may use an associative array to fetch the value via the variable name

Then it will be convenient to read the variable-value pairs directly within
bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash                 # declare an associative array
while read -r key val; do       # read key (variable name) and value
    key=${key#*[}               # remove leading "[" and the characters before it
    key=${key%:}                # remove trailing ":"
    key=${key%]}                # remove trailing "]"
    hash["$key"]="$val"         # store the key and value pair
done < <(./program_call)        # feed the output of "./program_call" to the loop

# then you can access the values via the variable name here

foo="${hash["variable2"]}"      # the variable "foo" is assigned to "value2"
# do something here

bar="${hash["variable3"]}"      # the variable "bar" is assigned to "value3"
# do something here
```

Some people criticize that `bash` is too slow to process text lines,
but we process just about 50 lines in this case. I tested a simulation by
generating 50 lines, processing the output with the script above,
repeating the whole process 1,000 times. It completed within a few seconds. (Meaning one batch ends within a few milliseconds.)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This seem to work ok and does not require file access. The only thing I could not figure out is how to put the data printed by awk into variables, that can be used within the shell script. I thought about using `declare`, but am not sure how to fill multiple variables

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am on the way home now and please allow me a couple of hours to answer. BR.

Comment: Just one question. How many lines does the `program_call` output? Around 20 or many lines?

Comment: Thank you very much and no hurry :) The `programm_call` will output ~50 lines in total

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have updated my answer with a different approach. If I'm in a wrong way, please let me know.

Comment: Shell while-read loops are extremely slow, and shell associative arrays are extremely slow so that shell loop populating an associative array will literally take orders of magnitude longer to run than using awk.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do the job efficiently AND robustly (your approach and all other current answers will result in false matches from some input and some values of the variables you want to search for):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

vars='variable2 variable3'
awk -v vars="$vars" '
BEGIN {
    split(vars,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tags[tmp[i]":"]
        tags["["tmp[i]"]"]
        tags["["tmp[i]"]:"]
    }
}
$1 in tags || ( (s=index($1,"[")) && (substr($1,s) in tags) ) {
    print $2
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
value2
value3
```

```
$ cat file | ./tst.sh
value2
value3
```

Note that the only loop is in the BEGIN section where it populates a hash table (`tags[]`) with  the strings from the input that could match your variable list so that while processing the input it doesn't have to loop, it just does a hash lookup of the current $1 which will be very efficient as well as robust (e.g. will not fail on partial matches or even regexp metachars).

As shown, it'll work whether the input is coming from a file or a pipe. If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and improve your example to show a case where this does not do what you want.